# Returning array of C strings as an Integer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return, c-strings

I am a beginner in [c](/questions/tagged/c). I have a function that returns the length and array of c strings. However, I am having hard time to figure out how to send both as an `int`. I have tried using `void` pointers, but compiler generates an error saying that returning a pointer (`int` expected). Moreover, I have tried implementing the aToI method, but didn't get the required result. I realize that I can only return the array of c strings and get the length of that using `strlen()` function. However, how can we send an array of c strings as an integer. Please explain with an example. Thanks 
Heres what my code looks like

```
int read_header( char *fileName , char **headerRow )
{
    int length= header_columns(fileName);
    headerRow[0]=(char*)malloc(length);
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    char **header;
    char *savedheader;
    char *returnPointer;
    int counter=0;
    header[0]=(char*)malloc(Max_Line_Length);
    char *pointer=header[0];
    while((c=getc(fp))!='\n')
    {
        if(c!='\n')
        {
            if(c==',')
            {
                length++;
            }
            *pointer++=c;
        }
        else
        {
            length++;
            *pointer='\0';

        }

    }
   pointer=strtok_r(pointer,",",&savedheader);
    while(pointer!=NULL)
    {
        headerRow[counter]=pointer;
        pointer=strtok_r(pointer,",",&savedheader);
        counter++;
    }
    returnPointer= headerRow[0];
    return &returnPointer;


}
```

I am reading the line of words separated by comma as characters. Then I am parsing those characters as c strings using strtok_r() method. Now, I need to return the headerRow array as an integer to another function.

Comment: returning the address is also creating error.

Comment: You shouldn't send an array of c strings as an integer, I think. Sending an array of ithem as multiple integers may not be good, either. You should have better ways to pass your data.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you want to generate an array of integers?

Comment: You need to post the code that is giving you trouble. The question cannot be answered without seeing the code.

Comment: One thing that would really help is if you post what you have tried. There is nothing magic about void pointers, but there are rules you must follow in their use. If you post what you've tried, we might be able to help. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the link describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: I have added the code that I have implemented. !

Answer (score 1):

you can't send an array as an int. you must pass the array as an array or a pointer to that array.  if you want to get both values back from the function,  create a structure that contains the int and the array and return the structured from the function.

Answer (score 0):

An example of passing an array of C strings, not as an integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(char ***return_str) {
    char string_to_return[] = "Hello, world";
    char string_to_return_2[] = "hoge hoge foo bar";
    char **array_of_strings = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
    char *ptr = malloc(strlen(string_to_return) + 1);
    char *ptr2 = malloc(strlen(string_to_return_2) + 1);
    if (array_of_strings == NULL || ptr == NULL || ptr2 == NULL) exit(1);
    strcpy(ptr, string_to_return);
    strcpy(ptr2, string_to_return_2);
    array_of_strings[0] = ptr;
    array_of_strings[1] = ptr2;
    *return_str = array_of_strings;
    return 2;
}

int main(void) {
    char **strings;
    int len;
    int i;
    len = func(&strings);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("string %d = %s\n", i, strings[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) free(strings[i]);
    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```